# Whitelisting friends' dynamic IPs w/o much extra effort from them

Tags: networking, security, iptables, dynamic-ip

I'm running a small https webserver using a Javascript-based program that I've heard isn't super secure. Fortunately, I only want a couple of friends to be able to access it - unfortunately they're not all very tech savvy and they've got dynamic IPs.

I've seen some references to dynamic DNS managers and using those to query the dynamic IP, but I'd rather leave the server open than deal with getting that set up for all of them. Are there any simpler alternatives for updating the dynamic IPs?

The current site is running on 8080 forwarded from 443 externally. My best thought is a more secure webserver used as a login client that is the default forward from 443 - once a login with a valid uname/pass is made that uname's previously used IP is removed from the special 443->8080 rule and the new IP is added. Are there any good Ubuntu-based services that could do this? (IE at the simplest just present a login and on successful login call a script w/ username as input?)

Or are there any other good systems available? I've currently got it configured to at least only have the ports open while the server is running but I'd like to be able to leave the server up more often.

Edit: **More specific information**
The server is a **virtual tabletop simulator** for D&D, called [FoundryVTT](https://foundryvtt.com/); it has a username/password system but they explicitly detail that it is not really a security thing so much as keeping your players out of eachother's hair. I'm not as familiar with server technologies, but a quick look at files shows info for **Electron**, **Chromium**, and a **node_modules folder** seems to say **Node.js(?)**. I'm running **Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.13.0-37**.

Comment: There’s not enough specific information about your web server to make a complete recommendation. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) which web server program you’re using (Apache, nginx, etc.) (2) the type of web site you’re hosting (forum, blog, chat, etc.). Depending on what stack you’re using, one option would be an old-school access password 

Comment: I've just edited to include this info (to the best of my knowledge). Thanks for the helpful feedback!

Comment: Yes, I can set it up to only accept certain IP addresses, but the others all have dynamic IPs from their providers and for some reason a couple of them seem to change more regularly than I'd expect normally. Something like every couple of weeks. It's not a huge issue to manually change the addresses in my server startup bash script, but I'm looking to automate it along with server startup/shutdown. Plus it'd be nice for them to be able to play away from their normal space without too many issues!

Comment: One solution maybe to setup local user accounts for all your friends in your FoundryVVT server computer. Set the computer as a `ssh` server. Tell your friends to `ssh` into your computer (using their respective username and private-public key pair) and run a script that will grab their IP address and update your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the options I could find online, so I went ahead and made my own (hopefully, mostly) secured system for allowing people to create user accounts, register and manage their IP(s), and request access to specific services. Once access is approved, iptables rules are configured for a given port->port forward for each IP, and removed when IPs are removed.

If anyone has the same issue and wants to try it out I'm more than happy to help get it working on more than just my system! Check out the source here: https://github.com/Matthew-Whitlock/secured-port-forward

I can put more documentation and flexibility if anyone ends up interested, but I'm not especially looking to over-engineer a personal solution without need.